# Using javascript to get value from numeric text input and multiply it by radio button

Tags: javascript, forms, input, radio-button, multiplication

very new to javascript. As far as I can tell other similar questions have been asked but i need a solution to bring it all together. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

I have the following form which needs to calculate a price based on {number of users} multiplied by {price of package}:

```
                    <form id="quote_form">

                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="input">
                                <label>Number of Users:</label> <input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="text" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="input">
                                <label>24/7/365 Support:</label> <input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:7px 0;" class="bgclear" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="input">

                                <table class="table-2 h7">

                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="color3">Select a package:</td>
                                            <td class="color2">Standard <input id="r1" name="radioCh" value="standard" type="radio" class="bgclear" /></td>
                                            <td class="color2">Standard + <input id="r2" name="radioCh" value="standardPlus" type="radio" class="bgclear" /></td>
                                            <td class="color2">Advanced <input id="r3" name="radioCh" value="advanced" type="radio" class="bgclear" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Mail Box</td>
                                            <td>30 GB</td>
                                            <td>30 GB</td>
                                            <td>30 GB</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>File Storage</td>
                                            <td>10 GB</td>
                                            <td>10 GB</td>
                                            <td>10 GB</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Microsoft Office</td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr> 
                                            <td>Microsoft Exchange</td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Antivirus</td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>CRM</td>
                                            <td><img alt="not included" src="images/cross.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Device Independent</td>
                                            <td><img alt="not included" src="images/cross.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>PBX &amp; VoIP</td>
                                            <td><img alt="not included" src="images/cross.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="not included" src="images/cross.png"></td>
                                            <td><img alt="included" src="images/tick.png"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>

                                </table>

                            </div>

                            <div class="input">
                                <a class="button-3" onclick="getTotal();_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Quick Quote','Calculate Button','Quote Generated']);">Calculate<img alt="calculate" src="images/buttons/button-3-arrow.png"></a> <div id="finalPrice"></div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>

                    </form>
```

And the following js that I'm using to return the value (I am aware that it's incomplete and currently wont grab the numeric value from the input box (no idea how to do this!)):

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

return true;
}

function getUserNumber() {
var employeeNum = 0;
var theForm = document.forms["quote_form"];
var numInput = theForm.elements["text"];
}

var monthFee = new Array();
monthFee["standard"]=60;
monthFee["standardPlus"]=80;
monthFee["advanced"]=95;

function getFastQuote() {
var fastQuote = 0;
var theForm = document.forms["quote_form"];
var radioButton = theForm.elements["radioCh"];

for(var i = 0; i < radioButton.length; i++)
{
    if(radioButton[i].checked)
    {
        fastQuote = monthFee[radioButton[i].value];
        break;
    }
}
return fastQuote;
}

function getTotal() {
var quotePrice = getFastQuote * getUserNumber;

document.getElementById('finalPrice').innerHTML = 'Price from: £' + quotePrice;
}
```

Comment: Values in inputs are TEXT, you need to convert them to numeric data types to do math. num = parseInt(val) or num = parseFloat(val)

Comment: FYI:  It's usually much quicker to get help if you make a jsFiddle illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not calling your js functions correctly. Your code is

```
var quotePrice = getFastQuote * getUserNumber;
```

while it should be

```
var quotePrice = getFastQuote() * getUserNumber();
```

Also read the comment by @Diodeus about type casting of the strings.
Your `getUserNumber()` method has no return value, so add `return numInput.value;` as the last line to that function.